# SwiftUi : Index out of range on an Array issued from Firestore

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, fatal-error

I'm new here and learning how to code with SwiftUi

I'm trying to figure out why I can't access to my array values issued from Firestore.
The class below read the datas from Firestore and fill an array datas: [category], where category is a struct.

The array seems to be well filled because when i'm printing values of this array it appears in the console.

```
class getCategoriesData: ObservableObject {

@Published var datas = [category]()

init() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("categories").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in

        if err != nil {

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        for i in snap!.documentChanges {
            let id = i.document.documentID
            let name = i.document.get("name") as! String
            let pic = i.document.get("pic") as! String

            self.datas.append(category(id: id, name: name, pic: pic))
        }

        //try inside getCategoriesData
        print(self.datas)
        print(self.datas[1])
        print(self.datas[1].name)

    }
}
```

But when I call my array from my View (code below), i get this error :

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

It seems the array isn't recognized in the View.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var searchText: String = ""
@ObservedObject var categories = getCategoriesData()

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        Text(categories.datas[1].name) //here the error appears
```

I don't get the point why I can access to my array from the getCategoriesData while I can't inside my ContentView..

Thanks for your answers
Jean

Comment: How many entries are there in `datas`? You’re referencing `datas[1]`, which is the second item in that zero-based array. Was that your intent? If you’re going to use numeric indexes, you need to make sure you’re not exceeding the number of items in that array. Also, `getCategoriesData` is retrieving data asynchronously, so almost certainly it’s got nothing in it yet by the time you get to the `VStack`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `getCategoriesData` is not a good name for a class. Class names should be nouns, and start with upper case letter, e.g. `CategoriesData`.

Comment: datas has 3 entries, in fact I used the index 1 in datas[1] only for a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your reply. I figured out how to handle le asynchronous retrieving with a if condition. I will post an answer so solve the topic. Sure, I should have used upper case letter, I'm starting code and still forgetting !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you cannot access your array from the getCategoriesData is because 
 "db.collection("categories").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in"
is an asynchronous function. That is, the results of it (and therefore init()) are 
not available until it is finished. Study a bit more about asynchronous functions and where to call them, typically not in init().

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to handle the asynchronous retrieving from Firestore thanks this code :

```
if self.categories.datas.isEmpty {
                Text("")

            } else {
                Text(self.categories.datas[1].name)
            }
```